Armature rigging issue
For the past few days, I've been trying to remake one of the mechanical robot arm taking inspiration from Ian Hubertz's work.
I have almost completed the rig for the entire arm except for the hands which will be a minor hurdle compared to the rest of the project itself.
Now I imported an animated mixamo figure with the "salute" animation. The main problem is I'm trying to make the primary bone of my rig a child of the Mixamo armature's right arm shoulder if that makes sense, and as I've tried to show it in the image attached below:

But when I do so, the entire rig goes haywire and it does follow the animation but not quite well you see.
Rigging issue on youtube
But if anyone knows the solution to fix this whole mess and get the arm moving in smoothly with the Mixamo armature with whichever animation please please help me out.
I've also attached the blend file if someone wants to further dig deep into the precise nature of this problem.
Robot arm blend file
